# Weird behavior of Color Input palette - Krajee Yii extension

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, yii, colorbox, kartik-v

**Description of the Issue**:
I'm facing an issue with the Spectrum Color Picker in my Yii2 project, specifically when it's used on medium-sized screens (e.g., laptops). When I resize the window, an empty right background appears in the color picker, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Empty Right Background]

**Issue Details**:

- The Spectrum Color Picker is integrated into my Yii2 project using the Kartik ColorInput widget.
- The issue occurs when I resize the window on medium-sized screens and causes the unexpected empty background on the right side of the color picker.

**What I've Tried**:
I've already tried to address the issue by modifying the CSS for the color picker container, specifically the `.sp-krajee.sp-container` class. I set `width: 100%;` to ensure it fills the parent container, but this hasn't resolved the issue.

Thank you in advance for your help!